# Trouble getting a very basic bash script to exit

Tags: bash

I have a colleague who is struggling to get `exit 0` to work.

```
jshint ./ | grep "[0-9] errors" | { read x; if [ ${#x} -gt 0 ]; then exit 0; fi; }
```

If I echo "test" instead of exit 0, it works (I see the echo), but if I try to exit 0, it doesn't exit properly.

Any ideas why?

Comment: 'it doesn't exit properly': expand.
NB grep already outputs an exit status of 0 confirming if it matched anything, ie the pipeline after grep is pointless anyway..

Comment: While not an answer to your immediate question, jshint most likely returns a useful error status, so your colleague should be using `if jshint ./ > /dev/null; then exit 0; fi`.

Answer (score 3):

> it doesn't exit properly. Any ideas why?

Your statement is a pipeline.  Each command in a pipeline runs in a subshell.  That means that `exit 0` exits only that subshell.

Answer (score 1):

You can rephrase your line like this:

```
x=$(jshint ./ | grep "[0-9] errors" | { read x; echo "$x"; })
[ ${#x} -gt 0 ] && exit 0
```

to avoid trying that `exit` in a pipeline subshell.

Also consider doing it like this:

```
x=$(jshint ./ | grep "[0-9] errors" | head -1)
…
```